# How to logout from a site by ending a session

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

I have a problem logging out of site. So far i have logged in, however, when i make a logout.php and include session_destroy(); it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code of each page.

Index.php:

```
<?php include ("login.php"); ?>
```

login.php

```
   <?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['loggedin']['user']=$_POST['user'];
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
    echo '<h2>Logged in</h2><p style="font-size:14px;">Welcome '.$_SESSION["user"].' you have sucessfully logged in.</p>';
}
else {
     echo '
       <h2>Login</h2>
       <form action="auth.php" method="POST">
       <div class="smallform">
                <p><span>Username:</span><br>
                <input type="text" name="user"></p>
                <p><span>Password:</span><br>
                <input type="password" name="pass"></p>
                <p style="padding-top: 15px"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
        </div>
        </form>';
}
?>
```

Auth.php:

```
   <?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("HOST", "USER", "PASS", "DBNAME");
$user = $_POST["user"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$sql = "SELECT UserID FROM Customer 
        WHERE UserID = \"$user\"
        AND Password = md5(\"$pass\")";

$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
<title>VeloCity</title>
<link href="_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=index.php" />'; ?>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
<?php 
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)==1){
    $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
    $_SESSION["loggedin"] = True;
    echo "You have sucessfully logged in";
}
else{
    echo "You have entered an incorrect password. Please try again";
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
?>
```

Another thing to add in the login.php i have a if statement, which is:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
    echo '<h2>Logged in</h2><p style="font-size:14px;">Welcome '.$_SESSION["user"].' you have successfully logged in.</p>';
}
```

The issue is as you can see it should display Welcome "USERNAME", originally it did however it doesn't now it just shows welcome you have successfully logged in.

I would like to thank everyone in advance for any help. Thank you

Comment: try to just `unset($_SESSION['loggedin']); unset($_SESSION["user"]);`. Instead of destroy

Comment: And your code has vulnerable for SQL injection. Use PDO and prepared statements to execute query http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this, on the login page you are defining `$_SESSION['loggedin']`:

```
$_SESSION['loggedin']['user']=$_POST['user'];
```

Remove that because otherwise, your:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
```

will always evaluate to `true` and show the welcome message, even if the user is not logged in.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. You were correct, it kept showing the message because of the mentioned code.

Comment: @Moe no problem. Why did you accept the other answer? This answer solves the problem, as you said yourself.

Comment: I can only accept one answer and they both helped me. Without your answer my problem would not be solved and without his answer it will not be solved.

Comment: @MrCode Well, technically I answered first. Why was a shift in accepting of answers? Seriously, is this the way people be inconsistent?

Comment: @Moe What do you feel? Shifting sides? Crazy world! This is the reason people don't feel answering or giving quality answers!

Comment: Praveen Your answer was quality and as i mentioned above, both of them helped me. I'm just confused, i just signed up today and not to sure how it works. Btw, your answer didn't actually solve my issue MrCode answer did. P.S: you have a bigger reputation, does one answer really matter this much?

Comment: @PraveenKumar your answer doesn't solve the problem, it has nothing to do with the session_destroy at all. Yes you're correct about input sanitization and deprecated mysql but that has nothing to do with the question being asked - your answer could have been a comment. Moe you have a free choice of which answer to accept, but keep in mind you should accept the answer that solves the problem, for the benefit of any other visitors that come to this page with the same problem.

Comment: OKay, agreed with both of you. `:P` @Moe LOL, can't answer your question! Tricky one. `;)`

Answer (score 2):

#### A few notes:

1. Your input is not sanitized.
2. Try not to use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead.

#### Use this code in the `logout.php`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // Because you are checking if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])), use the below:
    unset($_SESSION['loggedin']);
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the notes. i am still a beginner at PHP so no idea what PDO is but i will research it. I wouldn't mind some pointers tho.

Comment: @Moe Even am in the same boat. Check out this article so that we get going good: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php